# Running Docker using ConEmu

Tags: windows, docker, conemu

This is my ConEmu task setting

Task parameters: `/dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"`
Commands: `"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" "%ProgramFiles%\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"`

[image]

This is the result, I can see the whale but I cannot use any `docker` command, I got error: **bash: docker.exe: command not found**

[image]

Please help, thanks

> I'm using Windows 10, Docker Toolbox 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Just add Docker's path to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Windows 7 with running the Quickstart Terminal, I was getting the same error. After making sure Docker's path was in `PATH`, I tried running the Quickstart Terminal as administrator and it works fine.

I couldn't find anything online about it, but running as administrator works, but non-admin always gets the error that you got.